# rpm -e not cleaning up folders which are co-owned by many packages

Tags: rpm

Suppose we have 10 products all need to be installed under `/opt/xyz`.
`rpm -e` is not cleaning up directories on last uninstall.

The spec file is as below:

```
%dir
/opt/xyz/client/version/lib
/opt/xyz/client/version/bin
/opt/xyz/client/version/etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify

%dir
/opt/xyz/client/version/lib

rpm -qlp doesnt list any other folders under lib or above. 
So to remove all the parent folders installed by this package explicitly list them in %dir folder as below

```
%dir
/opt/xyz
/opt/xyz/client
/opt/xyz/client/version
/opt/xyz/client/version/lib
```

OR
in %files section specify the parent folder (this includes all the files folders under the folder)

```
%files
/opt/xyz
```

includes everything after xyz. So if you want to rpm to own install/cleanup specify in %files section. But if you want rpm own only few selective folders/files specify them in %dir section